# Dynamo DB - Is is possible to update/insert nested field

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a document in the dynamo DB in the following format.

{
  key1: "value1",
  key2: {sKeya: "A", sKeyB: "B" }
}

Is it possible to update (via JavaScript) directly nested field in the dynamo DB document? BCOZ I don't want to update key2 with all values again.

Example: I tried the below query, but did not work. It rather created one more field key2.sKeya: "ABC"

UpdateExpression: "set #field = :value",
            ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                "#field": "key2.sKeya"
            },
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ":value": "ABC",
            }

Has any one faced similar issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define the object key as separate Attribute names.

So one alias for "key2" and one alias for "sKeya".

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const DOCCLIENT = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  let entry = {
    TableName: "test",
    Key: {
      "key1": "value1",
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set #parent.#child = :value",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#parent": "key2",
      "#child": "sKeya"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":value": "ABC",
    },
    ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
  };
  DOCCLIENT.update(entry, function(err, data) {
    callback(null, 'done');
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens!